# Override Vuejs component from included component in my app

Tags: javascript, calendar, vuejs2, components, vue-component

I am working on a Vuejs app that incorporates [Vue Bootstrap Calendar](https://github.com/EazyServer/Vue-Bootstrap-Calendar). I really only need the calendar structure without events, and so I want to be able to override the contents of each day cell and put in my own custom content. I was able to do this [successfully](https://github.com/wonder95/formio-volunteers/blob/master/src/app/resources/shift/calendarController.js) with Angularjs using [Angular Bootstrap Calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar), but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this with Vue.

The [answer](https://github.com/EazyServer/Vue-Bootstrap-Calendar/issues/11) I got from the author was basically that I have to write my own component, and incorporate all the included libraries. However, since I just need to override [Day.js](https://github.com/EazyServer/Vue-Bootstrap-Calendar/blob/master/src/Components/Day.vue), even if I have to write my own component, since Day is one part of the overall component, how can I just include my component in such a way that it is incorporated as part of the VBC component without having to basically include all of that component in my code?

I've been looking at [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), and so fat that seems like the closest option, but I wasn't sure if I was going down the right path. Is there a way to override a component that I'm missing?